# uipagecontrol indicator(dot)issue

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

Hai All...

I want to change the uipagecontroller indicator(dot) color...For that i'm doing the below steps.

Create new class named as PageControl with 2 methods

1.- `(void) setCurrentPage:(NSInteger)page`

2.- `(void) setNumberOfPages:(NSInteger)pages`

```
- (void) setCurrentPage:(NSInteger)page 
{
    NSLog(@"setCurrentPage");
    [super setCurrentPage:page];
    NSString* imgActive = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"activeimage" ofType:@"png"];
    NSString* imgInactive = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"inactive" ofType:@"png"];
    for (NSUInteger subviewIndex = 0; subviewIndex < [self.subviews count]; subviewIndex++)
    {
        UIImageView* subview= [self.subviews objectAtIndex:subviewIndex];

        if (subviewIndex == page) 
            [subview setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgActive]];          
        else
            [subview setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgInactive]];           

        subview.frame = CGRectMake(subview.frame.origin.x, subview.frame.origin.y, 10,10);
    }
}


- (void) setNumberOfPages:(NSInteger)pages 
{
    NSLog(@"setNumberOfPages");
    [super setNumberOfPages:pages];
    NSString* img = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"inactive" ofType:@"png"];
    for (NSUInteger subviewIndex = 0; subviewIndex < [self.subviews count]; subviewIndex++)
    {
        UIImageView* subview= [self.subviews objectAtIndex:subviewIndex];            
        [subview setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:img]];        
        subview.frame = CGRectMake(subview.frame.origin.x, subview.frame.origin.y, 10,10);
    }
}
```

Already i'm having one view with pagecontrol and scrollview...Here what i'm doing is select the uipagecontroller from nib and choose identity inspector and select the class name PageControl(newly created class with 2 methods)it works for changing the color while swipe the images but,it didn't works for clicking the pagecontrol for moving to next page...

I don't know what shoud i want to include or what mistake i'm doing...please help me out to do this...

Thank You...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enable page scrolling on click of dot then you need to first of all associate the "value changed" property in your xib file to the action you set in your code.

I have implemented the same functionality in one of my projects so it will definitely work.

```
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
int page = pageControl.currentPage;
CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;

pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
pageControl.currentPage = page;

CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

// Set the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl. See scrollViewDidScroll: above.

}
```

Cheers

Comment: Hai Aditya...I have already written this code in my preview.m class.preview.m class xib has the pagecontrol i'm connecting the changePage action method with page control as"value Changed"...Newly created class for changing the pagecontrol indicator is called PageControl.open the pagecontrol in xib and select the class name as PageControl i.e.,(newly created class name).It change the Dot color while scroll the page .At the time click the pagecontrol to move to the next page it shows an ordinary indicator(without color)...Thank You so much for your Quick Reply...

Comment: I think this link will help you   http://www.onidev.com/2009/12/02/customisable-uipagecontrol/

Comment: Yeah this link help me more...Thank you Aditya

Answer (score 0):

Your above code is crashing in iOS 7.I have found a solution for this problem. I know it is not the way but Sure that it works till iOS 8 will be launched in the market.

Reason for Crash:

in iOS 7 `[self.subViews objectAtIndex: i]` returns `UIView` Instead of `UIImageView` and setImage is not the property of UIView and the app crashes. I solve my problem using this following code.

Check Whether the subview is `UIView`(for iOS7) or `UIImageView`(for iOS6 or earlier). And If it is UIView I am going to add `UIImageView` as subview on that view and voila its working and not crash..!!

```
-(void) updateDots
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        UIImageView * dot = [self imageViewForSubview:  [self.subviews objectAtIndex: i]];
        if (i == self.currentPage) dot.image = activeImage;
        else dot.image = inactiveImage;
    }
}
 - (UIImageView *) imageViewForSubview: (UIView *) view
{
    UIImageView * dot = nil;
    if ([view isKindOfClass: [UIView class]])
    {
        for (UIView* subview in view.subviews)
        {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            {
                dot = (UIImageView *)subview;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (dot == nil)
        {
            dot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            [view addSubview:dot];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dot = (UIImageView *) view;
    }

    return dot;
}
```

Hope this solve ur issue too for iOS7. and If Anypone find the optimal solution for that please comment. :)

Happy coding